# Does ActionLink take into account Global.asax routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an action like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink(dinner.Title, "Details", new { id=dinner.DinnerID })
```

and a route defined like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "PrettyDetails",
                    "{Id}",
                        new { controller = "Dinners", action = "Details" },
                        new { Id = @"\d+" }
                    );
```

The action link renders `<a href="/234">My Dinner</a>`

Why does it not display `"Details"` in the link? Is it because it knows about the routes defined in Global.asax and therefore matches the pattern somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does it not display "Details" in the link?

Because the route pattern you have defined in your Global.asax is `{Id}` where id must be an integer. So to answer your question, yes, the `Html.ActionLink` helper respects the routes you have defined in your Global.asax.

If you want to be able to pass a different action than `details` you will have to modify your pattern. For example like this: `{action}/{id}`. Obviously the same stands true for the controller part.

You could use the `Html.RouteLink` which allows you to specify a route name if you don't want the evaluation to happen in the order of your route definitions in Global.asax. This way you could target a specific route. Of course the arguments you are passing must be coherent with this route.

Comment: Does actionlink read the global.asax or are the routes in memory? Just wondering how it knows what to render?

Comment: The routes are stored in memory once the application starts.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "Yes", ActionLink is taking the defined routes into account when rendering the URL.